# Make every first line of table look the same

Tags: tables, color, captions

I've been struggling recently with tables. And I've finally managed to get past it. However, I'm now trying to make every first line of my tables look the same (bold white on blue background color). And I really don't know how to do that.

I know I must use a `\renewcommand`. So my guess is that:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}

\definecolor{Tab}{RGB}{79, 129, 189}
\renewcommand{
    tabular{
        <first lign of every tab>
    }{
        \rowcolor{blue} \textbf{\textcolor{white}}
    } \
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Exemple of First Colored Lign}
\begin{tabular}{m{3cm}|m{10cm}}
    \rowcolor{Tab} \textbf{\textcolor{white}{HeaderLeft}} & \textbf{\textcolor{white}{HeaderRight}} \\
    \hline Acronym
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
    \hline Acronym
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \\
    \hline Acronym
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \\
    \hline 
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}
    \caption{Exemple of Tab without a colored Lign}
    \begin{tabular}{m{3cm}|m{10cm}}
    \hline HeaderLeft & HeaderRight \\
    \hline Acronym
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
    \hline Acronym
        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \\
    \hline Acronym
            & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \\
        \hline 
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

But, well, it doesn't work. :/ What is the caption for the first line? I'm lost.

Do you know how to apply a specific style to every first header line of every table in a LaTeX document?

Comment: Ahem ... usually yes. Is it important ?

Comment: what doesn't work? Please make a complete small document that shows what you attempted, and the error that you get. Usually it is best not to redefine standard latex environments such as `tabular` they may be used internally in many different places. You should define your own command with a new name.

Comment: I've added a code but I don't know what I should use to achieve my goal so I can't even go for compile it doesn't have any sense. How can I select only the first lign of the tab ?
I just want to apply the colored row to every tabular header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possibility, using the method provided in [`this page`](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-wholerow) of the TeX FAQ:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}

\definecolor{Tab}{RGB}{79, 129, 189}

\newcolumntype{$}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
  #1\ignorespaces
}
\newcommand\MyTabHeadings{%
  \rowcolor{Tab}\rowstyle{\bfseries\color{white}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Exemple of First Colored Line}
\begin{tabular}{$l^l^l}
\MyTabHeadings
HeaderLeft & HeaderCenter & HeaderRight \\
text & text & text \\
text & text & text \\
text & text & text \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `>{declaration}` syntax provided by the `array` package allows to insert
`declaration` directly in front of each entry of the column (there's also `<{declaration}` to insert `declaration` right after each entry of the column, but that's not relevant here).

In the format specification for the `tabular`, the first column has to be preceeded by `$` and all other columns by `^` (those characters could be any other characters that don't usually appear in the format specification of a table).

When `\MyTabHeadings` is issued, `\rowstyle` is set, the style is applied in this column and stored in `\currentrowstyle` so it can be applied for the `^` columns.

For a normal row (one in which `\MyTabHeadings` is not issued), `\currentrowstyle` is set to `\relax`, so the `^` does nothing and the row doesn't change.

Comment: That works, thanks ! This is even better than what I wanted ! However, could you explain me why it works ? Because I don't understand the '$l^l^l' nor the use of the little token '>'.

Comment: @Xaltar sure! I'll add an explanation in some minutes.

Comment: @Xaltar I've updated my answer with a little explanation.